# ESC POS php library: does not work on USB shared printer via SMB protocol

Tags: php, xampp, smb, thermal-printer, escpos

I have a web server with xampp (windows 10) and a client PC with windows 7 with POS-58-series thermal printer (shared). When I enter the web app from Windows 7, printing doesn't work. if instead I reverse the roles of the PCs it works perfectly (W7 PC with web server).

This is my php code with library esc-pos (mike42)

```
    require 'escpos/src/Mike42/Escpos/Printer.php';
    require 'escpos/src/Mike42/Escpos/PrintConnectors/PrintConnector.php';
    require 'escpos/src/Mike42/Escpos/PrintConnectors/WindowsPrintConnector.php';
    require 'escpos/src/Mike42/Escpos/CapabilityProfile.php';
    require 'escpos/src/Mike42/Escpos/CodePage.php';
    require 'escpos/src/Mike42/Escpos/PrintBuffers/PrintBuffer.php';
    require 'escpos/src/Mike42/Escpos/PrintBuffers/EscposPrintBuffer.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;


$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://Armando-PC/pos1"); //pc with shared printer

    // Inizializza la stampante
    $printer = new Printer($connector);

$printer->text("\n");
    $printer->cut(); 
    $printer->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Zebra with EPL connected to USB. I have installed Zebra drivers for printer on USB, shared, enabled as "Zebra", here is my code (working...):

```
<?php

use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage;
use Mike42\Escpos\ImagickEscposImage;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';  
    
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("ZEBRA");
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$data = 'I8,A,001


Q200,024
q831
rN
S4
D7
ZT
JF
OD
R215,0
f100
N
A15,14,0,4,1,1,N,"Test etiketa"
X19,59,8,221,107
B56,125,0,E80,4,8,56,B,"56754773"
P1';
try {
    $printer -> text( $data);
     /* Close printer */
    $printer -> close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
}
```